# Arcade equivalent of Python ".zfill"

Tags: arcade

What is the equivalent of the "zfill" python function to set a specific number of digits for values in a field using Arcade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [Text | Text functions | ArcGIS Arcade | ArcGIS Developers](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/text_functions/#text)

> **Text**
>
> Text(value, format?) -> Text

The format parameter is where you can specify the number of digits.  For example:

```js
var num = 12004;
return Text(num, '000000');
```

yields:

```
012004
```

If you want to make it dynamic, it is a bit cumbersome but doable:

```js
var num = 12004;
var pad_len = 6;
var pad_char = 0;
return Text(num,  Concatenate(array(pad_len,pad_char)));
```

yields:

```
012004
```